# How do you escape a double quote while using sed?

Tags: file, bash, unix, sed, sh

I'm trying to remove all lines of text that contain a double quote,  and I have tried this:
`sed -ne '/\"/!p' theinput > theproduct`
It left the lines untouched. What do I do? Here is my script:
`touch tmp.txt
open tmp.txt
read -sn 1 -p "Paste in data and press any key to convert"
echo

```
touch tmp.txt
open tmp.txt
read -sn 1 -p "Paste in data and press any key to convert"
echo
sed -e 's/-/                             /g' tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
grep -v '"' tmp2.txt > final.txt
open final.txt
echo Study Conversion Successful
```

The first sed command works. It replaces a hyphen with a bunch of spaces (don't ask why I need that). The grep command, which I added from a response, does not work. It leaves the lines with quotes untouched.

Comment: Which OS if you don't mind my asking?  The `sed` and `grep` work fine in a Mac Snow Leopard console (BSD flavored Unix), as well as an Ubuntu 11.04 console (GNU).  Are you sure the double quotes are real and not smart quotes?  Maybe grasping at straws here but these commands should work.  Something odd is going on and we'd like to help.

Comment: Mac Snow Leopard. They are definitely double quotes.

Comment: Hmm, Snow Leopard here too. Works for me whether escaped or not.  Sorry to hear about this issue.  FWIW I have Bash version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not necessary to escape the double quote:

```
sed -ne '/"/!p' theinput > theproduct
```

Answer (score 1):

Very strange.  It "works for me"

```
$ cat data.txt
dsklfljs
sdjflk"Sdgsd"
sdfj sldkfj "Sdfsd"
sdfj 
sdf
sdjflks
$ sed -ne '/\"/!p' data.txt
dsklfljs
sdfj 
sdf
sdjflks
```

Perhaps it is a version issue with `sed`?

However, you can also consider using `grep -v` for this.

```
$ grep -v '"' data.txt
dsklfljs
sdfj 
sdf
sdjflks
```